# Simple battle class

Tags: java, beginner, game, battle-simulation

I'm new to Java, and this code could likely be squashed down a whole heap. How can I make this code simpler and easier to read?

`chance.base` is a percentage. If it is = 40, it has a 40% chance of returning `true`.

```
public class battleManager {

void battle(Army playerArmy,Army enemyArmy,int armyModifier,int army2Modifier){

    if(armyModifier > 40| army2Modifier > 40){
        System.out.println("note: modifiers were over maximum (40)");
    }
    chanceManager chance = new chanceManager();
    chance.base = (50 + armyModifier) - army2Modifier;
    int armyCount = playerArmy.units, army2Count = enemyArmy.units;
    boolean armyAlive = true, army2Alive = true, playerWon = false;

    while(armyAlive & army2Alive){

        if(chance.generate()){
            army2Count--;
        }
        else{
            armyCount--;
        }

        if(armyCount == 0){
            armyAlive = false;
            playerWon = false;
        }

        if(army2Count == 0){
            army2Alive = false;
            playerWon = true;
        }
    }
    chance.base = 25;
    int armyKilled, army2Killed;
    armyKilled = playerArmy.units - armyCount;
    army2Killed = enemyArmy.units - army2Count;

    for (int unit = 0; unit < armyKilled; unit++){
        if(chance.generate()){
            armyCount++;
        }
    }

    for (int unit = 0; unit < army2Killed; unit++){
        if(chance.generate()){
            army2Count++;
        }
    }

    // this is for debugging
    System.out.println("army survivors:");
    System.out.println(armyCount);
    System.out.println("army2 survivors:");
    System.out.println(army2Count);

    if(playerWon){
        System.out.println("player army won");
    }else
        System.out.println("Player army lost");
    // end of debugging

    playerArmy.units = armyCount;
}
```

Comment: 40, 50 and 25 are http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29 . Avoid them

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Naming

Class names should start with an `UpperCase` letter by convention.

What is a `battleManager`?  What is a `choiceManager`?  Why not `ColonelSanders` or `VicePresidentOfChoice`?  Joking aside, the naming could be more descriptive.  How about `BattleSimulator` and [`BernoulliTrial`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial)?

The naming of the parameters is inconsistent:

> ```
> battle(Army playerArmy,Army enemyArmy,int armyModifier,int army2Modifier)
> ```

Any of these would be more logical:

```
battle(Army playerArmy, Army enemyArmy, int playerModifier, int enemyModifier)
battle(Army army1, Army army2, int army1Modifier, int army2Modifier)
battle(Army attacker, Army defender, int attackerModifier, int defenderModifier)
```

The last option would be particularly appealing if the situation being modelled is asymmetrical (i.e., the attacker army is attempting to move into the defender's territory).  Typically, the rules would require the attacker to have at least *n* units, while the defender might have no units at all.  (An assertion at the beginning of the `battle` method to enforce such a rule would be a good idea too.)

### Object-oriented design

The `battle` method should be `public`, to be consistent with the class.

It would be useful for the function to return the winner of the battle.

Setting `chance.base` to modify the probability is not recommended, since you are allowing others to meddle with the internals of the `chance` object.  Three better approaches are:

- `BernoulliTrial battleProb = new BernoulliTrial(50 + army1Modifier - army2Modifier);`
- `battleProb.setProbability(50 + army1Modifier - army2Modifier);`
- `battleProb.generate(50 + army1Modifier - army2Modifier);`

See below for a more creative naming suggestion — I think it reads more nicely.

### Algorithm

There is a fighting phase and a healing phase.

After healing, you resuscitate some of `playerArmy`'s casualties.  However, you do not do likewise for the enemy army.  Either that is an oversight, or one of the healing loops is superfluous.  I'll assume that only the winning army should be healed.

Rather than setting the unit count after the loop, you could manipulate the army's unit count directly within the loop.

You would be better off without the `armyAlive` and `army2Alive` flags.

```
assert(attacker.units > 0);

BernoulliTrial attack = new BernoulliTrial(50 + attackerModifier - defenderModifier);
int attackerCasualties = 0, defenderCasualties = 0;

// Begin fighting
while (attacker.units > 0 && defender.units > 0) {
    if (attack.success()) {
        defender.units--;
        defenderCasualties++;
    } else {
        attacker.units--;
        attackerCasualties++;
    }
}
Army winner = (attacker.units > 0) ? attacker : defender;

// Heal the winning army
BernoulliTrial heal = new BernoulliTrial(25);
int winnerCasualties = (winner == attacker) ? attackerCasualties : defenderCasualties;
while (winnerCasualties-- > 0) { 
    if (heal.success()) {
        winner.units++;
    }
}

return winner;
```

Comment: The ternary inside the for loop is not very readable. :p

Comment: the `int units` variable is not used and its name is confusing because of `winner.units`. Plus I don't see the point of decrementing it. I would do `int healingCandidates = (ternary); while (healingCandidates-- > 0) {...}`. I also don't like that there are 2 ternaries.

Comment: @RobAu Rewrote the loop by popular demand (Rev 5).

Answer (score 8):

- **Naming** is inconsistent. Either armies should be `army1, army2` or related variables should be `playerArmyAlive, enemyArmyAlive` etc.
- **Symmetry** is broken. It is reasonable to expect `enemyArmy.units = army2Count` at the end of the method (otherwise why bother calculating `army2Count`?).

  More on symmetry. If both armies are to be resurrected indeed, factor that out in a method

  ```
  void resurrect(Army army, int killed) {
      while (killed-- > 0) {
          if (chance.generate()) {
              army.units++;
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Instantiating `chance` for each battle doesn't look right. It feels like a member of `battleManager`.  Same goes for magic constants `40` and `25`.
- `armyAlive` is redundant; it is synonymous to `armyCount == 0` predicate, which really feels like an `Army` method.

Answer (score 7):

A few that I could grasp:

- Usage of bitwise operators (`|` and `&`) instead of logical operators (`||` and `&&`). Though its correct but ensure you do not use it wrongly.
- boolean armyAlive, army2Alive can be avoided. Instead use the count.
- Combine the System.out.println-s into one line (if related).

  ```
  System.out.println("army survivors: " + armyCount);
  ```
- Use DEBUG flag to contain the logs so that its easy to switch between Debugging and otherwise.
- Updating arguments is not good. Assume them to be final. Instead return what needs to be updated. (Opinions for/against the same are invited).

  ```
  playerArmy.units = armyCount;
  ```
- playerWon can be calculated outside the while loop as follows:

  ```
  while(armyAlive & army2Alive){
      if(chance.generate()){
          army2Count--;
      }
      else{
          armyCount--;
      }
  }
  playerWon = (army2Count == 0);`
  ```
- If suppose the playerArmy or enemyArmy is null, have a validation check.
- A grievous mistake: if `armyCount` and `army2Count` is `<=0` , it will be a while before you know it.
- Do you want to know which modifier is `>40`. If yes, add it to the logs.

Answer (score 7):

I see a lot that we could help you with.

**Operaters**.

You use :

```
while(armyAlive & army2Alive)
```

You could rewrite it as :

```
while(armyAlive && army2Alive).
```

Short explanation : if first is false, it won't check statement 2. Your case both operands are always checked.
[Long explication here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4014535/2853637)

**Use correct methods**

Name may be strange, but what I want to say is, you are in the manager.
You want to do the battle between 2 Army's.
 
Why not returning the Army what won?
As you logical think about it, the battle just need to happen and you need to know in the guy who has won.

**Setting the right things at the right place.**

If it was me I would implement the method `isAlive` in the Army class like this :

```
public boolean isAlive () {
    return units > 0;
}

public void loseAUnit() {
    units--;
}
```

Then changing the code to :

```
int playerStartUnits = playerArmy.units, enemyStartUnits = enemyArmy.units;
while(playerArmy.isAlive() && enemyArmy.isAlive()){
    if(chance.generate()){
        enemyArmy.loseAUnit();
    }
    else{
        playerArmy.loseAUnit();
    }
}
Army winner = playerArmy.isAlive()?playerArmy:enemyArmy;

resurrect(playerArmy,playerStartUnits,chance);
resurrect(enemyArmy,playerStartUnits,chance);

return winner;
```

For the regenerating, @vnp already mentioned how you could do it, just he didn't mentioned that you would have to send the chancegenerator also to the method.

I just find it strange that you only set the player his units back and not the enemy his troops after the resurrection.
What I mean with that is that you resurrect the enemy troops also, but never set them back.
Or you delete the resurrection of enemy troops or you do set them back.

Answer (score 6):

```
void battle(Army playerArmy, Army enemyArmy, int armyModifier, int army2Modifier){
```

Try to avoid parallel data structures.  They make the system more fragile, as you have to maintain the relation.  If you need a parallel structure, try to keep the name consistent.  Here you seem to be calling it both `enemyArmy` and `army2`.

Why not make a `modifier` field in `Army`?  Then you'd be guaranteed to associate the right `modifier` with the right `Army`.

Consider renaming `modifier` to something like `strength` or `battlePower` that is clearer about what it does.  You could be modifying almost anything.  It's hardly better than `number`.

Also, any time you find yourself naming variables something like one and two, there's a good chance that you should be using a `Collection`.  Possibly a `List` in this case.

```
if(armyModifier > 40| army2Modifier > 40){
while(armyAlive & army2Alive){
```

You are using `|` and `&`.  You should be using the logical-only operators (`||` and `&&`).  The latter versions *short-circuit* and don't process the second operand if they can determine the expression value from the first operand.  You should almost always use them.  It won't really matter here, as the second expressions are pretty simple.  But there are some cases where using the short-circuit operators can improve performance.

```
if ( armyModifier > 40 || army2Modifier > 40 ) {
while ( armyAlive && army2Alive ) {
```

Even here, there may be some slight performance improvement.

```
    if(armyCount == 0){
```

This kind of check is risky.  What happens if you change your battles so that there is a \$1\%\$ chance that you do double damage?  Then it would be possible for your `armyCount` to go directly from \$1\$ to \$-1\$.  Your army might win with negative troops, since once it goes negative it can't get to \$0\$.  If this happens to both armies, you may continue until you go out of the integer bounds.

```
    if ( armyCount <= 0 ) {
```

This is safer and more robust in the face of code changes.  It will catch circumstances that a straight equality check would miss.

```
// this is for debugging
System.out.println("army survivors:");
System.out.println(armyCount);
System.out.println("army2 survivors:");
System.out.println(army2Count);

if(playerWon){
    System.out.println("player army won");
}else
    System.out.println("Player army lost");
// end of debugging
```

You shouldn't have this kind of debugging code if you are sending your code out for review.  By the time that you get a review, you should have removed this.  Consider writing unit tests to handle this kind of debugging.  Then it isn't cluttering your code when you run it for real.

I'd consider moving some of your logic to your `Army` class.  For example, you could replace the `armyAlive` variable with a method call:  `playerArmy.isActive()`.  You could replace your manual decrement of `armyCount` with `playerArmy.takeCasualty()` or `playerArmy.takeCasualties(1)`.  Later you could have a `playerArmy.healCasualties()` method.

Doing this not only simplifies `battle`, it reduces repeated code.  Assuming you pass the armies as a `List` named `armies`, you could say:

```
for ( Army army : armies ) {
    army.healCasualties(chance);
}
```

Now you no longer care how many armies are fighting.  You don't have to add a new loop for each one.  You just need to call the appropriate method for each, and the loop takes care of the "for each" part.  Now if you change the heal logic, you can change it for both armies without having to modify two pieces of code in parallel.

You might not even pass `armies` to your `battle` function.  If you had a constructor for `battleManager`, you could pass things like the `armies` and heal percentage then.  Perhaps `battle` takes no parameters.

Alternately, if you are going to keep things the way that they are, you should make `battle` a `static` method.  That makes more sense for a method that does not depend on any class fields.

```
public static void battle(List<Army> armies) {
```

This assumes that you also moved the modifiers into `Army`.

Comment: The modifiers might not be properties of the respective armies. Maybe they are functions of how much money is in the bank, or citizen morale, or technological advancement.